# Python Tkinter Progressbar indeterminate on Toplevel while function running

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I need a progressbar which should show that the programm is still running while a loop in a certain function is working, so all in all the issue is simple.

I found some useful threads here but none helped me. I think I am missing a detail.

Here is the function which needs up to 1 minute to be finished depending on how many blogs are used:

```
def bildinhalt_execute():

        tumblr_progress.start()
        taglist = tagliste_area.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        taglist = taglist.split(",")
        tumblr_alt_wert = tumblr_alt_wert_area.get("1.0", END)
        """ Resized das Bild proportional """
        with open('tumblr_credentials.json', 'r') as daten:
            data_for_login_tumblr_all = json.load(daten)
        for blog in data_for_login_tumblr_all:
            tumblr_zugangsdaten(data_for_login_tumblr_all[blog]["consumer_key"],data_for_login_tumblr_all[blog]["consumer_secret"],data_for_login_tumblr_all[blog]["oauth_token"],data_for_login_tumblr_all[blog]["oauth_token_secret"])
            im = Image.open(pfad_tumblr_1)
            basewidth = (im.size[0] - int(breitepx_area.get("1.0", END)))
            wpercent = (basewidth / float(im.size[0]))
            height = int((float(im.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
            im = im.resize((basewidth, height), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
            im.save(pfad_tumblr_1)
            """ Postet das Bild """
            pfad_tumblr_1_bild = pfad_tumblr_1
            pfad_tumblr_1_bild = str(pfad_tumblr_1_bild)
            tumblr_bild(blog, taglist, pfad_tumblr_1_bild, tumblr_alt_wert)
        tumblr_progress.stop()
```

I start the progress at the beginning and stop it at the end.
The progressbar itself is created on the toplevel root:

```
    tumblr_progress = ttk.Progressbar(tumblr_blog_root, orient='horizontal', mode='indeterminate')
    tumblr_progress.place(x = 300, y = 615)
```

The function is executed when this Button is clicked and thats the moment where the prograssbar should start to show progress

```
    wordpress_button_bild = Button(tumblr_blog_root, text = "Bild", width=7, bg = "powder blue", command=bildinhalt_execute)
    wordpress_button_bild.place(x = 10, y = 10)
```

Am I on the right side? Or do I have probably to use multithreading for this, have never worked with multiple threads could be very hard, so if multithreading is needed, a hint would be nice where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want a moving progressbar, use the 'determinate' mode and send the interval to the start() function.  The label and counter below are just there to do something for a while.  If you want the progressbar to show something like percent completion, then you would use "after" to schedule a function call to update the progressbar with percent done, similar to the label update's use of "after" in the code below.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from ttk import Progressbar

class ProgressBar_Label(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent=parent
        self.ctr=0

        self.p = Progressbar(self.parent, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=200,
                             mode='determinate')
        self.p.grid()
        self.p.start(75)  ## 75 millisecond interval

        self.label=tk.Label(self.parent, text="Start", bg="lightblue", width=10)
        self.label.grid(row=1)

        tk.Button(self.parent, text="Quit", bg="orange",
                  command=self.parent.quit).grid(row=10)

        self.update_label()

    def update_label(self):
        self.ctr +=1
        self.label["text"]=str(self.ctr)
        if self.ctr < 100:
            self.parent.after(100, self.update_label)
        else:
            self.p.destroy()
            self.label["text"]="Finished"

parent=tk.Tk()
PL=ProgressBar_Label(parent)
parent.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sadly I already tried that, thats not what I want. As far as I researched I have to use multithreading, its impossible without. But thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't use multiprocessing that much but the simple example below works.  Note that the root window is started outside the process and passed to the class, which in theory keeps it independent.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

try:
    import Tkinter as tk    ## Python 2.x
except:
    import tkinter as tk    ## Python 3.x

class ProgressBar():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry("75x50+900+100")
        self.ctr=25

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def start_countdown(self):
        """ a separate process in a separate GUI
        """
        self.root.withdraw()
        self.top_count=tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.top_count.geometry("75x50+750+50")
        self.label_ctr = tk.IntVar()
        self.label_ctr.set(self.ctr)
        label = tk.Label(self.top_count, textvariable=self.label_ctr)
        label.pack()
        if self.ctr > 0:
            self.top_count.after(750, self.update)

    def start_running(self):
        """ create the progress bar widget
        """
        self.top=tk.Toplevel(self.root, takefocus=True)
        self.top.title("Progress Bar")
        self.top.geometry("+700+200")
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.top, width=261, height=60, bg='lightgray')
        canvas.pack()

        rc2 = canvas.create_rectangle(15, 20, 243, 50, outline='blue', \
                                      fill='lightblue')
        rc1 = canvas.create_rectangle(24, 20, 34, 50, outline='white', \
                                      fill='blue')

        total=100
        x = 5
        while self.ctr:        ## move the small rectangle +5 or -5 units
            total += x
            if total > 311:
                x = -5
            elif total < 100:
                x = 5

            ## in a separate process so should not interfere with mainloop()
            time.sleep(0.2)
            canvas.move(rc1, x, 0)
            canvas.update()

    def update(self):
        self.ctr -= 1
        self.label_ctr.set(self.ctr)

        if self.ctr > 0:
            self.top_count.after(750, self.update)
        else:
            ## sleep to allow any remaining after() to execute
            ## can also use self.root.after_cancel(id)
            self.top_count.after(500, self.root.destroy) ## destroy root when zero is reached

root = tk.Tk()

PB=ProgressBar(root)
pr1=Process(target=PB.start_countdown(), args=())
pr1.start()

pr2=Process(target=PB.start_running(), args=())
pr2.start()

## start mainloop in a separate process as a function of the class
## don't know if this is really necessary or not
## the theory is, it is detached from the other 2 processes and so
##    can react to both independently
## also the mainloop() process can be killed=shut down properly

pr3=Process(target=PB.mainloop(), args=())
pr3.start()

## safety clean up
pr1.terminate()
pr2.terminate()
pr3.terminate()
```